# Xcode: property "text" not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My code doesn't work because it doesn't recognize the "text" property. I am using ObjectiveC
I have double checked everything, and cannot find an error. I am a beginner at programming, so forgive me for my mistakes. 
Help is much needed!
I am trying to create a timer for my app.

```
int timeTick = 0;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(tick)    userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)tick{
timeTick++;
NSString *timeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", timeTick];
labelTime.text = timeString;

}
@end
```

Comment: What type is labelTime?

Comment: You should post exact error

Comment: It would help to know how things are declared.

Comment: (And Objective-C is not a beginner's language.)

Comment: Please post the code where you declare `labelTime`

Comment: please post the code where you create IBOutlet for that label...

Comment: labelTime is just what I named my "time" label, I am trying to set it so that the  "time" label is the timer

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
self.labelTime.text = timeString;
```

?
Otherwise, I can not see the reason not to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a property, the compiler will declare a getter method and a setter method (unless it's readonly).  To create the instance variable and implementations for its method, you must synthesize it.

Synthesize your property by adding the following to the top of your .m file:
`@synthesize labelTime = _labelTime;`

It's saying: create methods named `labelTime` and `setLabelTime`:  The instance variable that backs these methods should be `_labelTime`.

Then, in your code, add:

```
self.labelTime.text = timeString;
```